# How to run unit tests on code that has failing assertions in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

In Xcode i am running tests on creating users based on ID. When a wrong ID is set the test should fail. Though this test fails since the method it tests has assertions in itself:

```
[[Apiclient sharedClient] findAndCreateUserWithID:nil success:^(Player *player) {
        STFail(@"should not be able to create player with no ID");
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
```

the method called:

```
- (void)findAndCreateUserWithID:(NSNumber *)ID success:(void (^)(Player *))createdPlayer failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    NSParameterAssert(ID);
```

Will fail the test when parameter ID is nil. I know this is a pretty stupid example since it will always fail, but there are more assertions allready in code that are more useful. Whats the best practice on running Xcode unit tests which test code that allready has assertions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSParameterAssert` throws an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSParameterAssert)) when its assertion fails. You can test that this happens with the `STAssertThrowsSpecificNamed` macro. For example:

```
void (^expressionBlock)() = ^{
    [[Apiclient sharedClient] findAndCreateUserWithID:nil success:^(Player *player) {
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        }];
};

STAssertThrowsSpecificNamed(expressionBlock(), NSException, NSInternalInconsistencyException, nil);
```

I use an expression block there to make it easier to put that much code in the macro.

Answer (score 2):

As of late 2014, if you're using the new testing framework XCTest, you'll want to use `XCTAssertThrowsSpecificNamed` instead of the older `STAssertThrowsSpecificNamed` method:

```
void (^expressionBlock)() = ^{
    // do whatever you want here where you'd expect an NSParameterAssertion to be thrown.
};

XCTAssertThrowsSpecificNamed(expressionBlock(), NSException, NSInternalInconsistencyException);
```